# needed plugins for parallax mobile web page

Tags: javascript, parallax

I need to build an web page that has parallax scrolling effect just like this one,

[Air Jordan 2012](http://www.nike.com/jumpman23/aj2012/)

I've searched for documents and plugins to build one like above but still haven't figured out how and am lost in panic now...:(

Does anyone know any plugins or references that I can refer to?

Thanks in advance for your help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin named Jarallax, you can check it out [here](http://www.jarallax.com/)

There are a few examples on there website.

Basicly what the plugin does it lets you add specific css for a scroll position.

lets say have margin-top: 0; at 0% and margin top 10; at 100%

it calculates what margin top to add at current scroll position.

Cool plugin to create parallax scrolling to multiple elements.